# Return passed parameter with fluent moq

Tags: c#, moq

Is it possible to return passed parameter to mocked method with fluent moq? 
From:

```
mock.Setup(m => m.Foo(
It.IsAny<string>())).Returns<string>(s => s);
```

to:

```
Mock.Of<Bar>(m => m.Foo(It.IsAny<string>()) == ???);
```

Comment: So you want to *Foo* to return the parameter it received as a parameter?  And then you want to return a *Mock.Of<Bar>*? That's like checking *if (true) { /*do something*/ }*.